# Reverse proxy to a specified server from pool, if specific server can't be determined

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

In my nginx configuration (taken from [here](https://sites.psu.edu/jasonheffner/2015/06/19/nginx-use-different-backend-based-on-http-header/)) nginx acts as a reverse proxy based on a `x_server_select` header value:

```
upstream apache {
     server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

upstream staging {
     server 127.0.0.1:8081;
}

upstream development {
     server 127.0.0.1:8082;
}

# map to different upstream backends based on header
map $http_x_server_select $pool {
     default "apache";
     staging "staging";
     dev "development";
}

server {
     listen 80;
     server_name example.com;
     location / {
          proxy_pass http://$pool;

          #standard proxy settings
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_redirect off;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_redirect off;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
          proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
          proxy_connect_timeout 600;
          proxy_send_timeout 600;
          proxy_read_timeout 600;
          send_timeout 600;
}
```

That works great, however if there's no `x_server_select` header present I want nginx to proxy request to a random server from upstream list. How can I do that?

Comment: You set the default to apache. Is there a distinction between no header present and the header set to an indeterminate value? I am thinking that you could add a forth upstream containing all three servers as the default case.

Comment: Thank you @Richard Smith. I have read the docs and just added all servers to apache upstream.